# Change fragment from ListActivity in Android Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, android-fragments, xamarin

I'm trying to change the current fragment after selecting item from dialog of listActivity

this my **listActivity.cs** class :

```
 [Activity(  Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Dialog" , Label ="Number list") ]
    class NumberListActivity : ListActivity 
    {
        string[] data;
        ArrayAdapter adapter;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            this.data = Intent.GetStringArrayExtra("list_numbers");
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.specific_contact_number_list_layout, data);
            ListAdapter = adapter;
        }
        protected override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            base.OnListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


            //Intent callFragment = new Intent(this, typeof(barMenu));
            //callFragment.PutExtra("callNumber", data[position]);
            //StartActivity(callFragment);

            ISharedPreferences preferences = GetSharedPreferences(SignInActivity.userSessionPref, FileCreationMode.Private);
            String UserNamevalueSession = preferences.GetString("UserNamevalue", "");
            String UserphonevalueSession = preferences.GetString("Userphonevalue", "");
            CallService.phone.Connect(data[position], UserphonevalueSession);
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            SqliteDB db = new SqliteDB();
            db.Insert(data[position], now.ToString());


            var frag = new MainActivity();
            FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.conent_fragment, frag).Commit();
            Finish();
        }
    }
```

Everything here works very well i just need to change the fragment after click the item

i tried this

```
var frag = new MainActivity();
FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.conent_fragment, frag).Commit();
```

but its give me

> 09-27 12:57:00.247 E/AndroidRuntime(11446):
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080079
>   (TurkeyanaCall.TurkeyanaCall:id/conent_fragment) for fragment
>   MainActivity{4b067018 #0 id=0x7f080079}

my **specific_contact_number_list_layout.xmal** code

```
<TextView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/number_list"
  android:textColor="#37c837"
  android:textSize="20dip"
  android:textStyle="italic"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginLeft ="20dp"
  android:padding ="10dp"
          />
```

And this is the layout that contains the Fragment that i want to change its named as **bar_menu.xmal**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/maintActivity_drawerlayout">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearView">
        <fragment
            class="TwilioClientTest.Android.MainMenuFragment"
            android:id="@+id/conent_fragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/maintActivity_navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow"
        app:menu="@menu/left_menus"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please post the detailed codes of `NumberListActivity` and the xaml codes?  So that we can know which fragment you want to change?

Comment: I added my xaml page layout code

Comment: Im changing the fragment from android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout its works well but i have phone book in my app and i want when click on the contact name i want it to call the contact and move to calling fragment i can call now because its calling using service but i want during calling to change fragment

Answer (score 1):

A few things going wrong here.

First you are trying to use an activity as a fragment.

`var frag = new MainActivity();`

Second, by default `ListActivity` sets the content view for you with a `ListView` included. Therefore there is no `conent_fragment` view.

If you want to just show the MainActivity you can replace

```
var frag = new MainActivity();
FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.conent_fragment, frag).Commit();
```

With

`StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));`

If you really want to use fragments you will have to change a few things. I can update my answer if this is the case.

**Edit for fragment**

Create a layout named `number_list`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/number_list_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

This important thing here is to add a `ListView` with the id `android:id="@android:id/list"`. This will replace the default.

Then inside your `OnCreate` add `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.number_list);`

Then when you want to show the fragment

```
var frag = new MainActivity();
FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.number_list_content, frag).Commit();
```

Comment: I was developing on the app , so i turned the main activity to fragment 
the MainActivity now is Fragment not Activity

Comment: i want use the fragment
and my mainActivity now is barMenu.cs

Comment: I made all those already my problem is i want to change the fragment from another class currently i change the fragment very well from NavigationView items but now i need to change the fragment again after item clicked 
my problem is i cant use FragmentManager inside another class or inside receiver

Comment: Are you sure you have added my suggestions? The original question was why "No view found for id 0x7f080079" and the reason for that is there is no "conent_fragment". I do not understand what you are asing now but it may be better to post that in a new thread.

Comment: i just need to change fragment from receiver or from any other where except the barMenu that is my mainActivity class